# Deserialize key from primitive avro scheme using KafkaListener

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, avro

In Kafka topic that I read message key is a primitive avro scheme **"string"**.

So when I deserialize it in common way with **KafkaListener**:

```
@KafkaListener(
            topics = {"topic"},
            autoStartup = "true"
    )
    @Transactional
    public void consume(@Payload(required = false) Node skill, @Header(OFFSET) Long offset,
                        @Header(RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String messageKey, @Header(RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                        @Header(RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) Long timestamp) {
```

I get "\n&7770000000000105411" instead of "7770000000000105411" or how it looks like in Idea:

[image]

How can I deserialize it?

I'm already tried with **StringDeserializer** for my key:

```
@KafkaListener(
            topics = {"topic"},
            properties = {
            ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG + "=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
    }
    )
```

but it didn't give any results.

Comment: If you have Avro data, then why are you not using Avro Deserializer?

Comment: @OneCricketeer , how do you recommend to use it?

Comment: The exact same way you have `StringDeserializer`? Change the class name to use Confluent's AvroDeserializer https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html#avro-deserializer ; Or, edit your `application.properties/yaml` files to do the same